# Check is variable has this text

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

```
$check = array("this", "that", "to be", "not to be");

$yes = $no = array();
```

I'm trying to check, is each item of array `$check` contains text "be".

If it is, then add it to `$yes`, otherwise add to `$no`.

Seems I have to use a regular expression, can you please help me to compose it?

Comment: Does it have to be the word be or will words like `believe` be accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to look for the complete word `be` and not `be` as a substring you can use:

```
$check = array("this", "that", "to be", "not to be");
$yes = $no = array();
foreach($check as $v) {
        if(preg_match('/\bbe\b/',$v)) {
                $yes[] = $v;
        } else {
                $no[] = $v;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach($array as $arr)
{
   if(in_array('be', explode(' ', $arr)) == true)  
      $yes[] = $arr;
   else
      $no[] = $arr;
}
```

Comment: This will get text like `believe` as well as the word `be`. Just thought that that should be pointed out.